# custom properties in junit test, something like application.setDefaultProperties

Tags: spring-boot, testing

I'm creating unit/integration test in Spring boot app and have difficulty to add test properties.

this is how main application get properties from src/main/resources/config.json file.

```
Config config = new AppConfig().config();
if (config == null) {
  System.exit(1);
}

application.setDefaultProperties(config.getSpringProperties());
application.run(args);
```

I'd like to put test config file under src/text/resources/ and use it for integration test with MockMvc. Is there any way to do it?

```
config.getSpringProperties()
```

returns Map

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You can define custom properties locations with annotations like `@TestPropertySource` or `@SpringBootTest(properties`

Here some resource on the topic: 
https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Old:

Just add a file named `application-test.properties` or `application-test.yml` and annotate the test with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

By this you can even have multiple profiles. Just add the `@ActiveProfiles("xyz")` and name the application properties file `application-xyz.yml`

Comment: the problem is config file for source code doesn't follow standard spring boot format so I have our own module to parse it and extract and convert spring specific properties to Map. In Application main method, I can do `application.setDefaultProperties(config.getSpringProperties());` to use properties in the Map. However, I'm still not clear how I can do it for Spring Test.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot automatically resolves test properties from src/test/resources/application.properties